# Simple Proof involving Standard Deviation

Tags: probability-theory

Show that:

$SD(ax) = |a|SD(x)$

I know it is trivial, however, I'm unsure on where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need three ingredients.

1. $\text{SD}(X) = \sqrt{\text{Var}(X)}$.
2. $\text{Var}(X) = E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.
3. $E[aX]=aE[X]$.

I will let you figure out the recipe. Start with $\text{SD}(aX)$ and go from there.

Comment: It's just substitution and algebra from there then, huh.